# При нажатии другой кнопки звук не прерывался

Tags: c#, winforms

Например, я меня есть пианино, при нажатии одной кнопки идет звук.

Если я нажимаю на другую - звук той кнопки пропадает и начинается от другой кнопки.

**Вопрос:** как сделать, чтобы они обе звучали?

```
private void button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) <br>
{
    System.Media.SoundPlayer player = new SoundPlayer(Properties.Resources._1);
    player.Play();
}
```

Comment: Что вы имеете ввиду под кнопкой,    клавиши на клавиатуре,  компонент Button или что то еще? Как вы запускаете звук?

Comment: Добавьте код, который у Вас уже есть (ту часть, что отвечает за вывод звука).
Как вариант, можно звук запускать в отдельных потоках.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте `System.Windows.Media.MediaPlayer`. Несколько экземпляров этого объекта умеют проигрывать звук одновременно.

Не забудьте подключить сборки PresentationCore.dll и WindowsBase.dll.

Кроме того, вы, наверное, захотите сохранить где-нибудь ссылки на запущенные плейеры, чтобы можно было остановить звук.

---

Ответ честно украден [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6241289/276994).

Comment: спасибо, а как подключить сборки? :)

Comment: @Valentin, думаю эту информацию вы без проблем найдете в интернете)

Comment: @Valentin: Проект -> правая крыса на References -> Add reference... -> Assemblies -> Framework, там выберите нужное.

Comment: @VladD , спасибо

Comment: @Valentin: Пожалуйста!